# MySQL - If Table A is LEFT JOINed to Table B, how do I ORDER BY a field in Table B?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, left-join

Here is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT  pts.pts_id, 
            pts.pts_name, 
            meds.*
    FROM    pts
            LEFT JOIN meds
            ON pts.pts_id = meds.pts_id_fk
    WHERE   pts.id_fk = $id
      AND   pts_current = 1
```

Table `pts` (ie Table A) has the following data:

```
pts_id   time
1        Joe
2        Jack
3        Jill
```

Table `meds` (ie Table B) has the following data:

```
pts_id_fk   time
1           7AM
1           8AM
1           9AM
2           7AM
2          10AM
3          11AM
```

I would like to `ORDER BY` the result of this query based on the `time`.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  pts.pts_id, 
            pts.pts_name, 
            meds.*
    FROM    pts
            LEFT JOIN meds
            ON pts.pts_id = meds.pts_id_fk
    WHERE   pts.id_fk = $id
      AND   pts_current = 1

ORDER BY pts.pts_id, meds.time
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm what about `ORDER BY meds.time`

Comment: hi @zerkms - where should I put it exactly?

Comment: @torr: in the very end of the query

Comment: i tried that and it ends up re-ordering the `pts` records and not the `meds.time` records

Comment: sorry I meant that your sugg orders the `time` correctly but messes up with the `pts` order - @michaels sugg below fixes that